# I would like to have my edit function to work when i click on the edit image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I would like to have my edit function to work when i click on the edit image. I have a function to edit an event but it wont work when i click on the image. The delete code works when i click on the event:
delete function/edit function:

```
  eventMouseover: function(event, domEvent) {
                var layer = '<div id="events-layer" class="fc-transparent" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:-1px; text-align:right; z-index:100"><a><img src="../../images/editbt.png" title="edit" width="14" id="edbut'+event.id+'" border="0" style="padding-right:3px; padding-top:2px;" /></a><a><img src="../../images/delete.png" title="delete" width="14" id="delbut'+event.id+'" border="0" style="padding-right:5px; padding-top:2px;" /></a></div>';
                $(this).append(layer);
                $("#delbut"+event.id).hide();
                $("#delbut"+event.id).fadeIn(300);
                $("#delbut"+event.id).click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                url: '<?=base_url();?>testcalendar/fullcalendar/delete_events.php',
                data: 'id=' + event.id ,
                type: "POST",
                });
                var nTime = 1 * 50;
                window.setTimeout("location.reload()", nTime);
                });
                $("#edbut"+event.id).hide();
                $("#edbut"+event.id).fadeIn(300);
                $("#edbut"+event.id).click(function() {
                    var title = prompt('Current Event Title: ' + event.title + '\n\nNew Event Title: ');

                    if(title){
                $.ajax({
                url: '<?=base_url();?>testcalendar/fullcalendar/update_title.php',
                data: 'title='+ event.title+'&id='+ event.id ,
                type: "POST",
                });
                    }
                });
            },
```

delete_events.php:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
 try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=develop-calendar', 'root', 'root');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
  exit('Unable to connect to database.');
 }
$sql = "DELETE from evenement WHERE id=".$id;
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
?>
```

update_title.php:

```
    <?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
// connection to the database
try {
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blackboks-calendar', 'calendar-boks', '19xantia');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
 // update the records
$sql = "UPDATE evenement SET title=".$title "WHERE id=".$id;
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
?>
```

When i click on the edit icon there is an prompt to edit the title but when i type in a new title and click on ok it wont update. i think that there is something wrong with my update_title.php file but i dont know for sure.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant generated HTML (for example with the webdeveloper firefox extension, firebug, whatever) and JS? And you talk about an "OK" button that i don't see in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem here

```
 $sql = "UPDATE evenement SET title=".$title "WHERE id=".$id;
```

Needs to be

```
 $sql = "UPDATE evenement SET title=" . mysql_real_escape_string($title) . " WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($id);
```

Comment: I'd say more. That needs to be `$sql = "UPDATE evenement SET title=" . $title . " WHERE id=".$id;` Look at the space before `WHERE`

Comment: Yeah I agree Dani you do need this spare before the WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the space before WHERE I edited already on previous answer.

You can also always try to debug what is returning by the script if you look into the Network tab inside Developer Console (F12 in most browsers).

Or check the results of the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '<?=base_url();?>testcalendar/fullcalendar/delete_events.php',
  data: 'id=' + event.id ,
  type: "POST",
}).done(function(data) {
  alert(data); // Only for testing
});
```